# How to return specific line from text file?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

Inside the "while" condition it displays the right line but when I try to display the same line outside the "while" it displays the last line of my text file.

```
public String path() throws FileNotFoundException { 

     Scanner s = null;
        String str;
    try {
      s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new 
    FileReader("src/main/resources/linda.txt")));
            do{
                str=s.next();
                if((s.hasNext(("get:"))||s.hasNext(("post:")) || s.hasNext(("put:")) || s.hasNext(("delete:"))))
                {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }while(s.hasNext());
        }
        finally{
            if (s != null) {
        }

}               System.out.println(str);

            return str;
```

}

I expect the output of this code to be
fraudcheck/ :fraudcheck/:, but the actual output is fraudcheck/: foo:

This is my text file

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
     info:
        title: Simple API overview
           version: 2.0.0
            paths:
             fraudcheck/:
           get:
           operationId: listVersionsv2
    summary: List API versions
  responses:
    '200':
      description: |-
        200 response
      content:
        application/json:
          examples: 
            foo:
```

Comment: Do you have to use Java? Other tools are better suited for the task

Comment: Add a `break;` once you have found the given line, it will exit from the `while` loop ..

Comment: Your loop keeps running until the end of the file.  It keeps storing lines in `str`, and just doesn't print them.  If there will only ever be one match, you can just return directly from within the loop once you have a match.

Comment: Thank you Arnaud!  It works now with the break;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define new variable **String result** and store your line in it when reach desirable condition and then output this variable.But execution of loop will continue and it's not efficient.

```
String result;
........
 if((s.hasNext(("get:"))||s.hasNext(("post:")) || s.hasNext(("put:")) || s.hasNext(("delete:"))))
                {
                    result = str;
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

.......
 System.out.println(result);
```

Thus if your need only one line it will be more effective if your put **break** in the end of condition block like this

```
if((s.hasNext(("get:"))||s.hasNext(("post:")) || s.hasNext(("put:")) || s.hasNext(("delete:"))))
                {
                    System.out.println(str);
                     break;
                }
```

In that case loop stops when condition is true and variable **str** will have value of desirable line.

Comment: Actually I need to read multiple lines, your answer was very helpful

Comment: can you aprove it in that case?

Comment: Yes your answer is very detailed

Answer (score 1):

The do-while loop runs until the end of the file.

Exit the loop with `break` once you have encountered the matching line.